# Data transfer object with O(1) lookup

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dto

Hi
I want to use a datatransfer object that is got by reading a database using NHibenrate and that has like 1000 records and I need to use this DTo carefully  wherein based on a certain key i select a value. My DTO will be seomthing like this.

```
public class DTO
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int schoolId;
    double value;
}
```

Now the problem is I get this as an enumerable.. Now from this enumerable based on the schoolid  id and name i need to select a value which I do as of now as follows:

```
 DtoList.Where(x=>x.name="name" && x.id=1 && x.schoolId=2).First();
```

Now the problem with this is it is an O(n) lookup and I want it to be O(1) which can be done by using an IDictionary.

I am wondering if I can make this DTO implement IDitcionary and then do the same. \

Is that possible? I think this is more from a c# perspective.

Also from an NHibernate perspective how this will work out.

Comment: Will this work for you ? http://ayende.com/blog/4548/nhibernate-streaming-large-result-sets

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the list once and then look it up multiple times, maybe it's worth creating another object, which will consist of a dictionary, and create it from a collection of DTOs:

```
struct Key
{
    string Name;
    int Id;
    int SchoolId;
}

class DictionaryObject
{
   IDictionary<Key, double> _dict;

   public DictionaryObject(IEnumerable<Dto> dtoList)
   {
      _dict = dtoList.ToDictionary(
             o => new Key { Name = o.Name, Id = o.Id, SchoolId = o.SchoolId },
             o => o.Value);
   }

   double GetValue(string Name, int Id, int SchoolId)
   {
      // if the key exists then...
      return _dict[new Key { Name = Name, Id = Id, SchoolId = SchoolId }];
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: how do i convert it given the example tha ti mentioned.. how do i generate the key?

Comment: I am wondering what is the gain of making the key that way. while using this dictionary too I need to build up a key which again is nt optimum.

Comment: Yes, but you only construct it once. This solution is only relevant if you construct the dictionary few times but use it many times.

Comment: yup thats true. but i need to select each one of these results. so I was wondering if I can make the key something like Name+id+schoolId so that I dnt need to build up the key

Comment: But in your suggestion, you build up the key anyway. You just build it up using the `+` operator instead of using a struct. You can use a hash or string concatenation, but a struct is more readable and easier to debug than a hash, and string concatenation will probably be much slower.